# getting parameter value of json object in java

Tags: java, json

I have a `JsonObject` :

```
{"result":[{"active":"true"}]}
```

How can I get value of active?

Comment: Have you looked at the JsonObject API documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> parsedMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
    });
```

We get a Map with key value pairs. With your input you will get a `Map<List<Map<String,String>>>`. So to get "active", you can use something like `parsedMap.get("result").get(0).get("active")` (Note: This is just a pseudo code)